# How to use Shortcode from one WordPress page in another WordPress page?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

Is there a way to use a shortcode that works in one WordPress page in another completely separate WordPress page?

Like if the shortcode was just a link, I could just use a href on the other page, but it's a shortcode [xxx] that needs to execute on the 1st Wordpress page that I want to display on another completely separate Wordpress page if that makes sense?

Comment: Have you tried? What error are you receiving?

Comment: Well I mean on a completely different domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but what if I didn't make the initial shortcode. So what I'm trying to do is use the shortcode from one domain on another domain. I could use frames to render it in the other domain but it's not ideal and doesn't always seem to work.

Comment: So for example I have www.website1.com Wordpress installed with plugins, a shortcode invokes content to display on the page. I want this content to display on www.website2.com. I cannot use the shortcode on website2 because the relevant plugin is not installed there. Basically display content rendered on website 1 on website 2. I could redirect www.website2.com to website 1 or use html frames, but is there another better way?

Comment: The shortcode renders part of the content on website1. I want to retrieve that content rendered. The only ways I can think of doing it is redirecting website2 to website1 or displaying website1 in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the shortcode multiple times, that is what the shortcodes do.
You can add `[my_shortcode]` on multiple pages even multiple times in one page. 
If you need t use it in different site (different domain) then you need to move its implementation (function) and registration something like `add_shortcode( $my_shotcode, $func );` to the other site.